# Write png to xlsx file with XlsxWriter in python?

Tags: image, python-2.7, python-imaging-library, xlsxwriter, stringio

Following the guide for XlsxWriter here:
[Docs](http://xlsxwriter.readthedocs.io/example_images.html?highlight=image)
I have tried using Pillow to get the png file. Then write to the worksheet using the guide from the link above. I tried to use StringIO.

```
    f = Image.open('/opt/folder/' + 'cc.png')
    output = StringIO.StringIO(f)
    f.save(output)
    f = output.getvalue()
    output.close()
    frontSheet.insert_image('B1', f, {'x_scale': 0.5, 'y_scale': 0.5})
```

The error message said that NoneType object is not callablePerforming.

```
    cc = Image.open('/opt/folder/' + 'cc.png')
    f = cStringIO.StringIO(Image.open('/opt/folder/' + 'cc.png'))
    cc.save(im2, 'PNG')
    frontSheet.insert_image('B1', cc, {'x_scale': 0.5, 'y_scale': 0.5}
```

The error message said that it cannot identify the image file. How do I write the png file to the worksheet?

Comment: Any suggestions? @jmcnamara

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can just insert the image directly without Pillow:

```
frontSheet.insert_image('B1', 
                        '/opt/folder/cc.png', 
                        {'x_scale': 0.5, 'y_scale': 0.5})
```

Comment: That gives me an error saying "cannot identify image file" @jmcnamara

Comment: Then it probably isn't a valid png/jpeg/bmp file.what happens when you open it in an app?

Comment: It opens up as normal with windows photo viewer because it is a png image file @jmcnamara

Comment: In that case [open an issue on Github](https://github.com/jmcnamara/XlsxWriter/issues) and attach the image to it.

Comment: Issue has been opened https://github.com/jmcnamara/XlsxWriter/issues/382

Comment: Issue closed on GitHub. The issue was with the image file.